# How to restrict Html tags in textarea in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I want to restrict insertion of html tags from textarea using yii2 validation. One way i know is using `htmlspecialchars(string)`. It converts html tags in escape characters. e.g., < to $lt;

But i don't want that i want to validate it before insertion and show validation message. Is there any validation rule in yii2 to restrict html tags

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific rule but you can create validation method that checks this.

Example implementation:

1. Filter input text with [HtmlPurifier](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-htmlpurifier.html) helper allowing all HTML tags - this is optional for input normalisation.
2. Set `$filtered` variable with text filtered with HtmlPurifier - this time it should be configured with the list of allowed HTML tags so everything else is removed.
3. Compare original input (or filtered input from #1 if applicable) with `$filtered` text - if both are the same it means input is valid.